# AngularJS - Separate base Controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have base controller:

```
class VehicleCtrl {}
```

I want to extend that controller and make two new ctrl in **separate files**.

*car.ts*

```
class CarCtrl extends VehicleCtrl { }
```

*boat.ts*

```
class BoatCtrl extends VehicleCtrl { }
```

I don't use webpack or any module boundler.
Is this possible to have car.ts in separate file.

Comment: this is Angular 2+, isn't it?

Comment: It's AngularJS, ES6 components that's looks like angular2

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info.

Comment: Yes, of course its possible.  What issue are you running into?

Comment: extending controllers looks like untipattern, we just moved all logic inside service and assign it to your controller function variables; easy to test and always know what to expect

Comment: @DmitriAlgazin nice, I could do that, but I want to know if it's possible just move this base controller (VehicleCtrl) to separate folder and then include it, because I'm getting error - Property 'xyz' does not exist on type 'Car' when I move VehicleCtrl to another file.